# Automatically embeding Google Calendar

Tags: python, google-api, google-api-python-client, google-calendar-api

I am using Python Google API V3 to manipulate the Google Calendar from the server side of my web application.

I would like users to be able to see new calendars they created through their web browsers.

The thing is that I cannot find the URL needed to pass to HTML iframe in order for it to show up on the site. No URL, nor part of it, like the ID in form xxxxxxxxxx@group.calendar.google.com.

Calendar dicts returned by

```
thecal.calendarList().list().execute()
```

contain nothing useful in regard to this problem.

Does anyone know how to achieve what I want? I cannot go adding each new calendar manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Google Calendar API is a rest API.  It returns data in Json format.  It will be up to you as the developer to create a nice calendar to display to your users.

You are not going to find any link to the web view in the API.   Solution create the web view from the data returned by the api.

Comment: I am trying to avoid just that. Otherwise I wouldn't need the G.C. at all. I can make my own DB and my own Cal, but I don't want to. Are you quite sure the API doesn't return the URL/ID to the web view anywhere? Would somewhere be any hack or do I have to reverse engineer the G.C. app?

Comment: I have been using said api for five years I am sure.   It stores data thats all its your responsibility to figure out how you want the data displayed.

Comment: Very well then. I don't need such a poor API. I am discarding it right now. Thank you!